# quickblox accepting video chat call issue

Tags: chat, quickblox

i am Using Quickblox for making video calls in my app.
I was able to successfully make a call, and to receive a new session. but  have a problem on receiving remote video track. after accepting the session. 
I am not sure if the problem is in the accepting the call, or not receiving the remote video track. I am having the error below in my log:

2015-12-03 23:15:22:005 New Video Chat Project[4680:1226691] rtc:: Set SDP with error: Error Domain=RTCSDPError Code=-1 "(null)" UserInfo={error=Failed to set remote offer sdp: Called in wrong state: STATE_SENTOFFER},

please let me know what you think.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: In my case ,Problem was in my code , offer was being created from both the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error stated above, pointing out that the call has been created more the once. Check you call methods if you have such Log. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could become not sent to local video to opponent.
You start local camera firstly.

```
  self.cameraCapture = [[QBRTCCameraCapture alloc] initWithVideoFormat:[QBRTCVideoFormat defaultFormat] position:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];
            [self.cameraCapture startSession];
```

After that,you have to modify your delegate method.

```
- (void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session initializedLocalMediaStream:(QBRTCMediaStream *)mediaStream {
 session.localMediaStream.videoTrack.videoCapture = self.cameraCapture; }
```

I hope it helps you.